# angular ssr require is not a function

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

Trying to run `npm run dev:ssr` on angular/ionic, it is giving me the following error. How do I go about this?

```
server\main.js:306
var crypto = require('crypto');
             ^
TypeError: require is not a function
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "crypto": [
        "node_modules/crypto-browserify"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace
var crypto = require('crypto'); to import * as Crypto from "plugin_name"; syntax

Comment: it is coming from the build, on the dependencies for `formidable/lib/incoming_form.js `